# How to compare all array elements in if() statement, using &&

Tags: javascript, arrays

what i want to do is, to compare if all array elements equals to 2, if so than do something, bellow is working code

```js
var colorIndex=[2,2,2,2,2,2];

if(colorIndex[0]==2&&colorIndex[1]==2&&colorIndex[2]==2&&colorIndex[3]==2&& colorIndex[4]==2&&colorIndex[5]==2){
  alert("every element equals to 2");
}
else alert("some elements !=2")
```

though in that case it happens manually and if a will push something to that array i will have to change code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

> The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

```js
var colorIndex=[2,2,2,2,2,2];
if(colorIndex.every(i => i == 2)){
  alert("every element equals to 2");
}
else alert("some elements !=2")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `every` function in Array.

```
const colorIndex=[2,2,2,2,2,2]
const IsTwoList = colorIndex.every(val=> val ===2)

if(IsTwoList){
    alert("every element equals to 2");
}else {
    alert("some elements !=2")
}
```

Comment: @flemethwow someone put in the time to give you an answer. Maybe test it before guessing that it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Instead of manually access every item in the array, make it function call the same method to check all item are 2

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward.

```
   let colorIndex=[2,2,2,2,2,2];

   let isTwo = colorIndex.every(ele => ele === 2);
   console.log(isTwo);
```

isTwo will be true if all elements are 2, false otherwise.